# Service Reference in Windows Service .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.5

I have created a Windows Service in .NET 4.5, and i have used webservice in it,but i am having  troubles running this service. It installs fine, but when it is started throws error. i am sure it is because of the reference i added, but when i tested this code in simple Desktop Application it works ok. Can anyone help and give some advice on how to correctly install windows service when we use webservice in it.

Thanks

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Your question is very vague and you will not get a satisfactory answer if you don't edit it.

Comment: i have edited it, i am not sure if someone picks it what i actually mean.

Comment: You may want to provide the error message along with additional details about the Windows Service, such as; what user account is the service running as, what types of endpoints/bindings, etc.